# How to Track Age and Gender using Flurry Analytics in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry

I am using Flurry 4.4.0 in my app.

I am calling below method whenever the user updates his gender and age. This method is at AppDelegate and I am calling in my view controller when ever applicable as [appDelegate flurryMethodCall].

```
-(void)flurryMethodCall
{


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            [Flurry setAge:16]; // this value will change
            //Use this to log the user's age after identifying the user. Valid inputs are 0 or greater.
            [Flurry setGender:@"f"];//this value will change

            [Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
            //note: iOS only allows one crash reporting tool per app; if using another, set to: NO


            [Flurry startSession:@"MY_API_KEY"];


        });
    });
}
```

When ever the user edited his gender and age the I need to store this information using Flurry Analytics as individual records.

When I went to Flurry website then it is displaying as below eventhough I am calling Flurry method.

**You are not currently tracking Age data.**

Any suggestions and ideas are appreciated......!

Thanks in Advance..